# Using Git list all changes on file on all remote branches

Tags: git

I would like to know all commits and branches that changed some file in my project. We are working in a big team and there are lots of feature branches that are live work in parallel. I would like to see if somebody else is working on the same file at this moment and it will merge it to develop in the future. It is important to include all remote branches and not just my local branches.
How I can accomplish this?

Comment: Does `git log --all --not develop -- '/path/to/file'` give you satisfactory output?

Comment: In terms of git, what exactly does "working on" mean?

Comment: thanks, @ef-dknittl-frank. That is what I was looking for :) I added --stat like git log --all --not develop --not master --stat -- '/path/to/file' so I can see the amount of lines was changed because for some reason original command was showing some commits that are merge commits and didn't change any lines in this file.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen by "working on" I mean commits on the same file on other remote branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will show you all commits that modify a given file, while excluding all commits that are already merged to the develop branch:

```
git log --all --not develop -- '/path/to/file'
```